# Живой поиск как в Google

Tags: android

Есть приложение, которое использует БД в которой есть таблица с 2 полями. На форме есть EditText и кнопка. Когда в текстовое поле вводим слово и нажимаем OK то выполняется запрос и в TextView выводятся все записи соответствующие введенному слову.

Собственно вопрос в чем: Реально ли сделать так, чтобы когда в EditText начинаешь вводить буквы, то выпадал список предлагаемых вариантов как при поиске в гугл?

Не работает все равно. Вот что получилось

```html
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Создаем объект типа DictionaryDBHeler
        db = new DictionaryDBHeler(this);

        //Вызываем методы создания и открытия БД
        try {
            db.createDataBase();
            db.openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        // Настраиваем адаптер
        ArrayAdapter<?> adapter =
                ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // Вызываем адаптер
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
        txtResult.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        txtSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSearch);
        txtSearch.setThreshold(3);//Указываем сколько символов нужно ввести, чтобы появились варианты автозаполнения
        btnSearch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null,
                new String[] {DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 0);

        txtSearch.setAdapter(scAdapter);

        scAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence str) {
                return getCursor(str);
            } });

        scAdapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() {
            public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cur) {
                int index = cur.getColumnIndex(DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD);
                return cur.getString(index);
            }});
    }

    public Cursor getCursor(CharSequence str) {
        String query = "SELECT " + DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD + " FROM " + DictionaryEntry.TABLE_NAME
                + " WHERE " + DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD + " = " + "\"" + str;
        Cursor cursor = db.database.rawQuery(query, null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, реально. Посмотрите на компонент `AutoCompleteTextView` в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html). Это обычный `EditText` с адаптером.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49422/discussion-on-answer-by-pavel163-----google).